# List system date in 3 different formats? (Oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I came across one question where I have been asked to list the system dates in three different formats:

I used the following two formats but I'm wondering what could be the third one?

Format #1: SYSDATE

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

FORMAT #2: SYSTIMESTAMP

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions173.htm

I'm using Oracle 11g. Please let me know if above format are correct or not and what will be the third format in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Dan Bracuk's answer a little, you can build up three format models from the [datetime format elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA). Three typical ones might be:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as format1,
    to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as format2,
    to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-RR') as format3
from dual;
```

which in my locale gives:

```
FORMAT1    FORMAT2    FORMAT3
---------- ---------- ------------------
2013-04-20 20/04/2013 20-Apr-13
```

Depending on which part of the world you're in and local custom, you might prefer the second one as `'MM/DD/YYYY'`, to give `'04/20/2013'`.

Answer (score 3):

If I were asked that question, I'd use

```
to_char(sysdate, 'SomeFormat')
```

thrice.